# I can see pyaudio version installed in pycharm but it doesn't work

Tags: pycharm, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, pyaudio

I have installed PyAudio via Pycharm terminal.

Initially it was showing error so I did it using

```
1pip install pipwin
2pipwin install pyaudio
```

[image]

But when I run my program it do not work.
[image]

Comment: Screenshots seem the same

Answer (score 0):

add this `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)`  after the line `with sr.Microphone() as source:`   and magic happens, let me know